# Set different color schemes for different applications in GNOME Terminal?

Tags: colors, gnome-terminal

In the GNOME Terminal, the default scheme for text and background colors is the system theme, which on Red Hat seems to be just a slightly darker variant of the built-in scheme Tango dark. This works well and looks good in the shell, but when running Emacs in terminal mode, text with dark font color can be very hard to discern from the dark grey background, and I find that the build in theme White on black works much better (it's also possible that Tango light would work well, which would give Emacs an appearance closer to the standard appearance of windowed Emacs).

Is it possible to set the color scheme on an application basis? Such that in normal shell, the system theme is used, while when e.g. running Emacs in windowed mode, White on black is used?

Comment: Can't you just set this in your `~/.emacs` file?

Comment: @terdon How do I do that? I tried doing `(set-background-color "black")` to get a black background instead of the dark grey one, but it had no effect in terminal mode. It did have an effect when running Emacs in windowed mode, though (at first I was confused as to why Emacs looked so different, until I realized that that line I had left in my `~/.emacs` maybe had an effect after all).

Comment: @terdon Besides, even if I could somehow change the background color to black in Emacs in terminal mode, difficult to discern text might still be a problem in other applications and then I want to have a fix that works for them too.

Comment: There won't be a global solution, it is the application itself that controls the colors, so you will always have to configure it on a per-tool basis. I don't know how to set this for non-X emacs, my emacs theme is respected by `emacs -nw` run from a GUI terminal window, but not if I drop to tty. But this is emacs, so I am sure it is possible. Maybe ask over at [emacs.se]?

Comment: @terdon What do you mean not if you drop to tty? Also, when you run `emacs -nw`, do the colors in Emacs remain the same if you change the color scheme of the active profile? In my Emacs they change, so they apparently depend on the terminal's color scheme in some way.

Comment: When I run `emacs -nw` from a terminal emulator in my Cinnamon session, it has the same color scheme as when I run `emacs` and get a GUI window. However, if I drop to a tty (Ctrl+Alt+F3 or whatever) and run `emacs`, there my theme is not supported and I get the default black one.

Comment: @terdon Aha. Then it sounds like the GNOME Terminal behaves as your tty in that sense.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137092/discussion-between-terdon-and-hellogoodbye).

Comment: 1. The palette colors can be configured dynamically, using the OSC 4, 10, 11, 104, 110, 111 escape sequences. Just write a wrapper script in front of your Emacs that sets the exact colors. Alternatively: 2. get past the legacy of 8, 16 or 256 palette colors, use true colors (aka direct RGB) which has been available for quite a while now in GNOME Terminal, and I presume Emacs too. Configure Emacs to emit the exact RGB colors you wish to see.